# Excel VBA - Looping an IF( & VLOOKUP( starting with a partial string

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, vba

Good day to an amazing community,

I am trying to develop a macro to loop through two arrays. Here is an example of how the data is set up:

Raw data is found in C4:C1500

$ data is found in D4:D1500

Partial string values (originaly pulled from Raw data) are in E4:E13.

Categories the Raw data will organized into are in F4:F13

Below is the formula I pieced together as a proof of concept.

=IF(VLOOKUP(" * "&E4&" * ",$C$4:$C$1500,1,0)=ERROR.TYPE(#N/A),"Research",VLOOKUP(" * "&E4&" * ",$E$4:$F$13,2,0))

This works one line at a time, and only until the bottom of the short lists (without writing a massive nested statement). I'm trying to loop the Partial & Category values through the Raw data to then analyze the data by Category & $.

Example: Sheet1

| Row | Column C (C4:C1500) | Column D (D4:D1500) | Column E (E4:E13) | Column F (F4:F13) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | Raw Data | $ | Partial Data | Category |
| 4 | 210324Sales.BobParr.UT | 785.54 | BobParr | Sales |
| 5 | ABCDEF.210324.SalesHelenParr.TN | 214.46 | HelenParr | Sales |
| 6 | DashParr.WY.RR.210324 | 238.56 | DashParr | Research |
| 7 | Mgmt.NY.JackJackParr.210324 | 1,200.00 | JackJackParr | Management |

Sheet2:

| Rows | Column B (B4:B13) | Column C (C4:C13) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | Category | Total $ |
| 4 | Sales | 1,000.00 |
| 5 | Research | 238.56 |
| 6 | Management | 1,200.00 |

From there I will do another VLOOKUP( to SUM( expenses found in Sheet2.

I'm open to all suggestions for both cleaning up the testing formula, and will be grateful for all support with the VBA.

Thank you.

Richard VO

Answer (score 1):

I don't see the need to use VBA. If you have Excel 365, you can combine FILTER, CHOOSECOLS and SUM functions to obtain the desired results. Adapt the following formula:

```
=SUM(CHOOSECOLS(FILTER(Sheet1!$C$2:$F$5,Sheet1!$F$2:$F$5=Sheet2!$B3),{2}))
```

Bring the formula down to fill the other cells.

[image]

Comment: `CHOOSECOLS()` wins. Nice formula =) But Sir, why have you used curly braces at the last, will it not work without it. `{2}`?

Comment: @MayukhBhattacharya The `{2}` is to select only the second column as the FILTER function is returning 4 columns. This make it easier to then sum the amounts.

Comment: Ok, but is it needed within curly braces.

Comment: @MayukhBhattacharya Not needed. Before using CHOOSECOLS, I hade planned on using two FILTER functions. o, I was using the curly braces with one of them, then kept it when I changed my formula.

Comment: alright understood sir